# How to make a maintainable Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

1. Should I follow edge Rails from the beginning? Or just pickup the latest stable release and upgrade as new versions come about?
2. Should I give users more freedom on authorization settings? Example: fine grained authorization in Django's admin interface
3. I think testing is a must, but I have no idea which testing framework to start with, Test::Unit/Minitest/RSpec and Cucumber?
4. Haml or ERB?

p.s. Only one developer - me at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Latest table release and upgrade on new release
2. I use Devise for authentication, cancan for rights, activeadmin for administration
3. A very big question, me and a lot of other developpers use RSpec
4. Erb

It's my opinion but there is nothing definitive.

Try it and do your own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

1) Latest stable, upgrade as needed/desired.

2) Depends on the application, there's a lot of great plugins/gems that do [authorization](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization)/[authentication](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) so there's bound to be something out there to match you and your users needs.

3) Easiest to stick with the built in Test::Unit for starters.

4) Again, go with the built in ERB at first.

IMO. YMMV.

Comment: good points. What's your reason for ERB? It's a little bit hard for me to write html by hand after using Haml for months..

Comment: Several, working with vanilla HTML with just some ERB tags in it was always more straight forward for me. I like how close the template looks to the final rendered HTML. There is a speed and "short code" gain to using HAML, but I'm not writing large enough quantities of HTML to make that layer of abstraction worth it. I'd rather just see the HTML and edit it as needed. Also keep in mind in the future its possible other people will maintain this app, I think they are more likely to easily understand ERB.